# Review the errors on this page. missing required field: [ParentId]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, console

I am trying to open the case comment in custom lightning console app programmatically. The case comment  opens in new tab but I get an error when I hit the save button. Please refer to  code and image below.

**controller**

```js
({
   onInit : function(component,event,helper){
        
   }
    ,focusNewTab : function(component, event, helper) {
        
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.openTab({
            url: '/lightning/r/Case/5002v00002JtTuHAAV/view',
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            workspaceAPI.openSubtab(
                {
                parentTabId: response,
                url: '/lightning/o/CaseComment/new',
                focus: true
            });
       })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
})
```

**component**

```xml
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
    <lightning:button label="Focus New Tab" onclick="{! c.focusNewTab }" />
</aura:component>
```

[image: check the error in image that comes after hitting save button]